# Selenium does not find element by name

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium WebDriver to find an element on a page. The page opens, but the field is never found.

testing page:

```
<applet...>
    <param name="password" value="Password" />
</applet>
```

selenium script:

```
WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("password")); //always timeout
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selenium by itself cannot test java applets, check out FEST http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Selenium

*EDIT*

This issue has been broached before on the selenium users group as well https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/selenium-users/applet/selenium-users/h8o8MrurxDQ/5J7ppui38o8J there are some more tools you can use in the question there as well